# Is there a way to finish manual task synchronously (without waiting for async result) if some precondition is satisfied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am using AWS SWF and flow framework. I wanted to make my activities idempotent so that a workflow can be restarted from the beginning after any failure. Many of the activities are manual tasks (@ManualActivityCompletion) which need to be completed asynchronously.

Is there a way to finish manual tasks like normal tasks if I know that it is already complete? This way a new manual task will not be scheduled everytime the workflow is retried.

Or, is there a way to retry a workflow so that it starts from the point it failed?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to override activity completion behavior at runtime. The work around is to complete activity using ManualActivityCompletionClient from within activity implementation.
There is no supported way to retry workflow to start from the point of failure.